# std::unordered_map::find and count with key as argument fail to compile

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I am getting some cryptic errors while compiling some code for a project. I am using an `std::unordered_map` to store sections of the world in a game so multiple people can play in the same area without confusing the server. In world_manager.hpp, I have a key structure:
    
    `struct chunk_key {
          int32_t cX, cZ;
          uint8_t dimension;
     };`

And an unordered map:

```
 
    std::unordered_map<chunk_key, class chunk*, chunk_key_hasher> chunk_buffer;
```

In world_manager.cpp I have a function named 'chunk_is_loaded' to test whether a chunk already exists in the map. This is where the errors start.
    
    `bool    chunk_is_loaded(chunk_key* key)
    {
        if(chunk_buffer.count(key) != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }`

The error is at 'chunk_buffer.count(key)', where GCC gives the following error:

> world_manager.cpp: In function ‘bool           
>       world::chunk_is_loaded(world::chunk_key*)’:
>  
>       world_manager.cpp:8:34: error: no matching function for call to 
>  ‘std::unordered_map world::chunk_key_hasher>::count(world::chunk_key*&)’
>  
>                if(chunk_buffer.count(key) != 0)
>  
>                                     ^
>  
>       world_manager.cpp:8:34: note: candidate is:
>  
>       In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/unordered_map:48:0,
>  
>                    from world_manager.hpp:7,
>  
>                    from world_manager.cpp:1:
>  
>       /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:560:7: note: 
>  std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::size_type  
>     std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::count(const 
>  key_type&) const [with _Key = world::chunk_key; _Tp = chunk*; _Hash = 
>  world::chunk_key_hasher; _Pred = std::equal_to; 
>  _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::size_type = long 
>  unsigned int; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, 
>  _Alloc>::key_type = world::chunk_key]
>  
>              count(const key_type& __x) const
>  
>              ^
>  
>       /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:560:7: note:   no known 
>  conversion for argument 1 from ‘world::chunk_key*’ to ‘const key_type& {aka       const world::chunk_key&}’

I don't understand the error, and when I pass the key by value it gives me longer strings of errors even more cryptic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `key` is of type `chunk_key*`. The actual type of the key in the map is `chunk_key`. Spot the difference.

Comment: It gives me about 32000 characters worth of errors if I change it to be a chunk_key rather than a pointer to one.

Comment: I find it somewhat strange that you're passing keys around by pointer rather than by value or by reference. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::unordered_map<chunk_key, class chunk*, chunk_key_hasher> chunk_buffer
```

The key to the map is of type "chunk_key" and not "chunk_key*".

I suppose your intention is not to store chunk_key as an object, but, as a pointer.

If so, please update the map declaration. You also have to make sure that chunk_key_hasher() understands chunk_key*.

Otherwise, you should be doing

```
if(chunk_buffer.count(*key) != 0)  // dereference key
```

But, most certainly this is less efficient compared to storing pointers in the map, without c++11 considerations.

Comment: Alas, I tried passing *key as well. That also fails to compile as there is no operator for that. I wrote an operator that returned 'this'. Once again, failure. Then I modified it to return '&this'. Still failing, and with too much output for me to post here.

Comment: I need to use a chunk_key as a key so other parts of the program can generate a key that they can pass to the functions handling the world when they need to access a chunk.

Comment: @user: Based on your responses, I think you're in that situation where you need to take a deep breath and stop trying to make tweaks to fix the error and instead look at everything involved to figure out what things *should* be. (and then tweak things to become what they should be)

Comment: I fixed the issue by having my hash function make the keys, which are now of type `int32_t` , so now my `std::unordered_map` has `int32_t` as the first template parameter and `class chunk*` as the second template parameter. I no longer need to provide my own hash function for the `std::unordererd_map`.

Comment: @MamaLuigi: having your hash function produce keys sounds like a mistake: unless you know the hash output will be unique (which you normally don't with a hash function), you'll end up with distinct `chunk_key`s producing the same hash and unable to co-exist in the `unordered_map`.